# How to combine procs to filter a list in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lambda, closures, proc

I am trying to implement a filter-by-criteria approach in a little project of mine. I have a Filter class, in which i have filters for name, year, genre. For example:

```
Filter.new.name("The Shawshank Redemption")
Filter.new.year("1994")
Filter.new.genre("drama")
```

I also have a list of movies, each being an object that has methods name, year and genre. I want to be able to do the following (MoviesContainer is just a class that has a @movies list):

```
MoviesContainer.filter Filter.new.name("The Godfather") & Filter.new.year("1972") | Filter.year("1974")
```

I can easily overload the |, & and ! operators in my Filter class, but I don't know how to combine the filter object so that they become just one object which I can pass to filter.
I'm gladly accepting any ideas. :)

My best idea so far is to create a proc for every Filter.new and then combine them in the &,| and ! methods, but I don't know how. I'm thinking something like this could work, however, it doesn't :D

```
proc { |movie| proc { |movie| movie.name == "The Godfather" } && proc { |movie| movie.year== "1972" }
```

and then call this with every of the @movies items.
Can you please help me with the combining procs thing, or perhaps propose a better solution. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, seems that procs should work. You can also check out [Origin](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/), it's a query DSL extracted from Mongoid.

Comment: I think so, too. But I can't get it to work, so I asked the question here. A simple PoC will be enough for me :)

Comment: Check out @sawa's answer. Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
class Filter
  attr_accessor :proc
  class <<self; alias :old_new :new end
  def self.new attribute, value
    old_new.tap{|f| f.proc = ->x{x.send(attribute) == value}}
  end
  def & other
    self.class.old_new.tap{|f| f.proc = ->x{proc.call(x) && other.proc.call(x)}}
  end
  def | other
    self.class.old_new.tap{|f| f.proc = ->x{proc.call(x) || other.proc.call(x)}}
  end
  def !
    self.class.old_new.tap{|f| f.proc = ->x{!proc.call(x)}}
  end
end

class Movie
  attr_accessor :name, :year, :genre
end

MoviesContainer = [
  Movie.new.tap{|m| m.name = "The Godfather"; m.year = "1972"},
  Movie.new
]

module Enumerable
  def filter f
    select(&f.proc)
  end
end

filter1 = Filter.new(:name, "The Godfather")
filter2 = Filter.new(:year, "1972")
filter3 = Filter.new(:year, "1974")

MoviesContainer.filter(filter1 & filter2 | filter3)
# => [#<Movie:0x000000017dba08 @name="The Godfather", @year="1972">]
```

Comment: Can you please explain `class <<self; alias :old_new :new end` and add a ! (negative) operator. :)

Comment: That is to override the original constructor. Since you want to use `new` with arguments, and want to also create new instances of `Filter` with `&` and `|`, you need to save the original `new` and then redefine it. You cannot do that with `!` because that syntax is built in, but you can use a different method like `neg`. See my edit.

Comment: First off: `new` is not a constructor, it's just a method like every other method. There are no constructors in Ruby. Secondly: there is no need to `alias` it, since there is no `new` method anyway. You can just override the one you inherited from `Class` and call `super` just like with any other method, since `new` *is* just any other method. Thirdly: of course, you can override the unary prefix `!` operator. The name of the corresponding method is `!`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thanks for the correction. I edited to use `!`. But I don't know what to do with `new`. How can I access the `new` of the superclass in the `&`, `|`, and `!` methods and still get an instance of the original class? Perhaps it helps if you edit my answer.